# Firebase dynamic link fails to launch iOS app during password-less auth

Tags: firebase-authentication, ionic3, firebase-dynamic-links, password-less

Firebase is sending the password-less auth email correctly from my app via a 'Sign up' button, the 'magic link' in the email is taking me to my dynamic link domain, but I'm getting stuck at that point and the app is not being opened.

I've got an Ionic 3 application built for iOS using Firebase for the back end. I'm trying to implement Firebase password-less auth and followed this tutorial:

https://medium.com/@vivek040997/how-to-implement-firebase-email-link-passwordless-login-in-ionic-4-for-android-4c61f331c4a0

I've added my iOS app to Firebase, and in project settings, added the bundle ID, 10 char. app ID and 10 char. development team ID. The app has been created on App Store Connect, although it's not live in the App Store yet.

I've placed the GoogleService-Info.plist file into the root of my Ionic 3 project.

I've enabled email/password and password-less auth in Firebase.

As per the tutorial, I created a new index.html page (configured as a single page app using Firebase tools with some simple "logging in..." text) and ran '$firebase init hosting' and '$firebase deploy'.

I enabled Firebase dynamic links through my Firebase console, sticking with the simple 'my-app.page.link' domain.

I installed the Firebase dynamic links plugin for Cordova by using:

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks -- variable APP_DOMAIN="my-project.web.app" --variable PAGE_LINK_DOMAIN="my-app.page.link"
```

I was sure to use the correct project app domain (from hosting) and page.link domain. My package.json includes:

```
"cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks": {
        "APP_DOMAIN": "my-app.web.app",
        "PAGE_LINK_DOMAIN": "my-app.page.link"
```

My config.xml file includes the correct values, eg.:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="GoogleIOSClientId" value="my-value" />
</platform>
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="GoogleAndroidClientId" value="my-value" />
</platform>
```

I also installed the Ionic native plugin:

```
$npm install @ionic-native/firebase-dynamic-links
```

The plugins seem to be working correctly as I built a simple page to capture an email address and send the 'magic link' email. That works. I'm receiving the email correctly.

When I click on the magic link on my iOS device (opens in Safari), I see a 'preview.page.link' page with my app name, a little checkbox saying "Save my place in the app. A link will be copied to continue to this page." and an 'Open' button.

Clicking that button takes me to my Firebase hosted index.html page with the "logging in..." text I added, but hangs there. The app does not open so I just stay in Safari on that page.

I'm stuck now :(

No idea how to debug this further.

Any ideas how to get the redirect to open the iOS app correctly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you figure out how to prevent that "preview.page.link" and redirect to the app instead?